# Change ag grid body viewport

Tags: css, reactjs, web, react-bootstrap, ag-grid-react

I am trying to implement agGrid react. I have a wrapper that has a height of 300px but when I put the items into ag-Grid, the grid doesn't scroll and the rows are not accurately displayed. From inspecting the html I found that changing the ag-body-viewport height manually to less than the grid height solves the issue, however I want to override the height for body-viewport from my css file, is there a way I can achieve that ?

**AgGrid Implementation**

```
<Row className={`dds__mb-4 ${styles.agGridHeight}`}>
            <Col>
              <SkeletonWrapper
                toRender={() => (
                  <AgGridWrapper
                    className={`${styles.agGridHeight}`}
                    gridApi={gridApi.current as GridApi}
                    data-testid="add-users-select-role-grid"
                  >
                    <p>{}</p>
                    <AgGridReact
                      columnDefs={columnDefs()}
                      rowSelection="multiple"
                      rowMultiSelectWithClick
                      suppressRowClickSelection
                      pagination={true}
                      paginationPageSize={6}
                      suppressPaginationPanel={true}
                      defaultColDef={{
                        sortable: true,
                        flex: 1,
                        minWidth: 100,
                        filter: false,
                        resizable: true,
                      }}
                      domLayout="normal"
                      frameworkComponents={{
                        customNoRowsOverlay: CustomNoRowsOverlay,
                      }}
                      noRowsOverlayComponent="customNoRowsOverlay"
                      rowData={roles}
                      onGridReady={onGridReady}
                      suppressCellSelection
                      context={this}
                      accentedSort
                      localeText={{
                        loadingOoo: "Loading",
                        noRowsToShow: "Nothing to show",
                      }}
                      scrollbarWidth={3}
                      alwaysShowVerticalScroll
                    />
                  </AgGridWrapper>
                )}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
```

**Wrapper**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import { Props } from "./AgGridWrapper.interfaces";

const AgGridWrapper = ({
  gridApi,
  className,
  children,
  ...otherProps
}: Props) => {
  const wrapperRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const setWrapperWidth = useCallback(() => {
    if (wrapperRef.current) {
      wrapperRef.current.style.width = "auto";
      gridApi?.sizeColumnsToFit();
      wrapperRef.current.style.width =
        wrapperRef.current.offsetWidth + 1 + "px";
    }
  }, [gridApi]);

  const toggleTimer = useCallback(
    () => setTimeout(setWrapperWidth, 300),
    [setWrapperWidth],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setWrapperWidth();

    window.addEventListener("resize", setWrapperWidth);
    window.addEventListener("uicNavLeftExpandEvent", toggleTimer);
    window.addEventListener("uicNavLeftCollapseEvent", toggleTimer);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", setWrapperWidth);
      window.removeEventListener("uicNavLeftExpandEvent", toggleTimer);
      window.removeEventListener("uicNavLeftCollapseEvent", toggleTimer);
    };
  }, [gridApi, setWrapperWidth, toggleTimer]);

  return (
    <div
      className={`ag-theme-material ${className}`}
      ref={wrapperRef}
      {...otherProps}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default AgGridWrapper;
```

**CSS**

```
.ag-grid-border {
  border-radius: 4px !important;
}

.ag-grid-height {
  height: 27vh;
}


.ag-body-viewport {
  height: 223px;
}

.inputWidth {
  width: 40%;
}


.gridColHeight {
  height: 100%
}

.ag-body{
  height: 'inherit'
}
```

**Output:**

[grid with disabled/not working vertical scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENJK3.png)

Can someone please help me fix this issue?
I am assuming that fixing the height of viewport should fix this, Is there a way I can override the required ag-grid class styles from my css file?